# initial window.orientation always 0 on Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, windows-phone-8, mobile

I'm trying to detect device orientation on my website.

Orientation value seems to be ok after `orientationchange` event.

```
$(window).on("orientationchange",function(event){alert(window.orientation);})
```

However problem is initial window.orientation value at page startup which is always 0 even when device is in landscape position.

```
$(document).ready(function(){alert(window.orientation);});
```

It doesn't change after some delay (i've checked that) it changes to right value only after `orientationchange` event.

Is there any way to get proper orientation at page startup?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that property isn't actually supported in anything other than chrome for android: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation

Depending on what it is you want to do you could use CSS rules?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
  /* rules that only apply for canvases narrower than 1000px */
}

@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  /* rules for iPad in landscape orientation */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width:    480px) {
  /* iPhone, Android rules here */
}
```

Comment: It is supported in Windows Phone - when i do rotation the orientation value is correct, problem occurs before any device rotation. I cannot use CSS rules becouse they refer to screen dimensions, not to window.orientation value itself which can be different for some devices even if both are in landscape position e.g. http://pioul.fr/cross-device-cross-browser-portrait-landscape-detection

Comment: @pawlakppp if you actually read the article you linked yourself, it states that window.orientation should not be trusted and it also gives examples of how different browsers give different results in the same situations

Comment: it should not be trusted if you want get landscape/portrati position basing on window.orientation. I do not want that. I use accelerometer values from javascript and i use relative x or y Acceleration values basing on window.orientation. Thats why I need that.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried approaching the issue like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        alert(window.orientation);
    });
});
```

alternatively you can get the orientation of the device manually:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert((($(window).width()>$(window).height()) ? 90 : 0));
});
```

Comment: Yes i tried similar approaches but it doesn't change at all. I cannot get orientation manually because some devices are in orientation = 0 when window.width is higher than window.height - e.g Galaxy Tab (http://pioul.fr/cross-device-cross-browser-portrait-landscape-detection)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it on a Windows Phone and there it works. Which phone/os/browser are you using?

Comment: WP 8.1, browser is standard IE. Could you open this JSBin: https://output.jsbin.com/guvixu in landscape position and what value will be shown?